# What can cause socket erro 10060

Tags: delphi, indy

I'm using TcpClient and when try connect to a external server i receive the error socket error 10060.
What can cause it?

because if i use a TClientSocket and try connect to the same port (using TServerSocket) he connect fine without any error like what occour on indy.

Comment: Error 10060 is `WSAETIMEDOUT`. `TIdTCPClient` and `TClientSocket` use the same WinSock API internally, but `TClientSocket` does not implement any kind of connect timeout logic, like `TIdTCPClient` does. The ONLY ways you can get this error in `TIdTCPClient` but not in `TClientSocket` is if either 1) they are connecting to different Host/Port, or 2) you have a non-infinite timeout assigned to `TIdTCPClient` and it is timing out before the connection succeeds, whereas `TClientSocket` waits however long it takes to succeed. Make sure the `ConnectTimeout` is reasonable for your network.

Comment: ConnectTimeOut from TIdTcpClient are 0, what value you recommend use?

Comment: When `ConnectTimeout` is 0 or `IdTimeoutDefault`, it gets treated as if `IdTimeoutInfinite` were assigned instead. But, if `TIdAntiFreeze` is used on your Form, an infinite `ConnectTimeout` gets reduced to a hard-coded 2 minute timeout instead.

Comment: yes i use IdAntiFreeze1 on my form, so i should remove the IdAntiFreeze1 and let ConnectTimeOut 0?

Comment: 2 minutes is more than enough time to connect to most servers. Is there a firewall/proxy between your client and server? I just can't see how `TClientSocket` would succeed but `TIdTCPClient` would fail if they are connecting to the same Host/Port, since they use the API to make the connection.  Are you using the `TClientSocket` in blocking or non-blocking mode? Do you have the same problem if you move your `TIdTCPClient` to a worker thread and get it out of your main UI thread?

Comment: TClientSocket work as ctNonBlocking method, yes have a firewall of windows but are disabled. About TIdTCPClient connect run on a SetTimer (Thread)

Comment: `TIdTCPClient.Connect()` calls the underlying socket API `connect()` function in a thread and waits up to the `ConnectTimeout` for that thread to terminate. If it does not, the socket is forcibly closed and the thread is terminated and then a `WSAETIMEDOUT` error is raised. In VERY rare cases, I have seen times where a thread terminates normally but other threads waiting on it are not notified of its termination. I doubt that is happening here, but you would have to step into `TIdTCPClient.Connect()` with the debugger to verify.